# Excel export to CSV coverts numbers to string

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, export

I'v got the following data in Excel which I export to CSV. However, as you can see in text editor, the "Mval" values are often encapsulated by quotes. I assume this is because in Excel the number formatting has a "," separating the thousands.
[image]

Is there any way to export the data above as CSV without Excel wrongly recognizing numeric values as text (despite their number formatting)?

Comment: Is the "Mval" column formatted as Text or Number?

Comment: It's formatted as number

Comment: It's only the values that have a comma, or values greater than 1,000. What about changing the format of that column to show the value without commas... such as  3098.85.

Comment: That works. However, I would like to keep the number formating as it is. I am just curious to know why Excel does not simply export the numbers as they are but instead exports them they way they are displayed in the cell (along with their number formatting).

Comment: So basically, I would just need a command to export the values as CSV but without their formatting

Comment: I imagine it's "an Excel thing". I'm not aware of a way to change a setting to effect the result you want. Think of the exporting to CSV operation along with its inverse -- import from CSV (this is the original intention of the import/export feature). If you wanted to export/import a "0", then make the value a "0" instead of a "-".  When you import a CSV block with a "-", it can only be interpreted as a string hyphen ("-") because there is no formatting information in a CSV file to map a "-" to a "0" value. Same thing with a numerical value embedded with commas.

Comment: You could add a helper sheet (meant just for the CSV export), which connects to the sheet which is formatted the way you like. Then format the helper sheet in such a way that it produces the correct CSV output.

Answer (score 0):

Having a field quoted in csv does not mean that the value is of type string (csv has no types).

The quotes are there because there is a comma in the field, and this is the way it should be. Any csv reader should read the data fine.

If you want to keep the number format as it is now (including the comma) and really don't want quotes, you can try to change the delimiter to `;` (or tab).

Comment: Make sense, thanks! i would like the number format to be there in the .xlsx file, but when I export it to .csv, I would like the number format NOT to be visible in the export.
The idea is to have the number format in the .xlsx file, but still be able to process the csv file in other software e.g. R. Exporting the number format as well in the csv makes it extremely hard to read numeric values as they were in R.

Comment: @rajomato In that case you'll probably have to use a helper sheet as jkpieterse explains in the comments.